# Redirecting a URI to a PHP file using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the below .htaccess file in the root directory of the site.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Also I have the below folder structure.

```
.htaccess (root)
ow_plugin
    - service
         - controller
               - api.php
```

My requirement is that when users go to **www.mysite.com/api** it should be routed to the api.php present in the above directory structure. I am really confused on reading about various .htaccess guides.

How can I map the URI to that particular php file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is URI of `api.php` at present?

Comment: I have not defined any routes as Oxwall API will restrict if there is any different URI defined. I just want to directly route to that php file.

Comment: What do you mean by map it? You what to call /api and then redirect to api.php?

Comment: yes sir. I meant to say "redirect"..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ow_plugin/service/controller/api.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Comment: Is this the correct path `ow_plugin/service/controller/api.php` to api? If you go to that file in the browser does it work?